# how to access component tree in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there a way in angular 2 to access component Tree or a specific component instance given is selector or css class associated wth it or something like we do in jquery to find DOM elements from its css?

Comment: Inject `ApplictionRef` into a component.  There is a `_rootComponents` array that can at least get you to the root component.  I haven't tried digging any further.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug and view the component tree for any angular app is by using [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/), which is a popular dev tool extension available for chrome as well as firefox.